# rails delete cookies created by jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a cookie using jquery as follows

```
var test = $.cookie("test", 1);
```

And on loading a `new action` my rails app will call following action

```
def delete_cookie
    cookies.delete :test
end
```

But it is not actually deleting the cookie. Any suggestions how can i do it.

**Edit 1**

In my delete_cookie

if i use

```
cookies[:test] = nil
cookies.delete :test
```

the empty test cookie is deleted. But if i comment `cookies.delete :test` empty cookie is created.

Comment: im not 100% sure but can you try cookies["test"].delete

Comment: @Raghu It throws exception `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to so simply reset it:

```
cookies[:test] = nil
```

BTW, [doc states](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html) there is a delete method: `cookies.delete :test`

Comment: it is not resetting. it is created another cookie as `test with empty value`. so i have one test with value 1 and another test with empty value

Comment: try `cookies['test'] = nil`

Comment: this too creating cookie with empty value

Comment: `cookies['test'] = nil if cookies['test']`

Comment: no change same response. But if i delete cookie with value 1 manually in browser it delete the other cookie too. What is happening i couldn't understand

Comment: just use `.delete`, btw, what's the issue to you have an empty cookie?

Comment: I am unable to delete cookies this is the issue

Comment: I know it is in browser. Did you check by creating cookie with jquery and delete with rails?

Comment: Yes I do that to get timezone